# Can I completely hide a field in an HTML table and reference it in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in an apex HTL page. This table populates some records from a db cursor. In a jQuery process I am referencing the field `f_prod_id` but actually I don't need to display it on my screen. I don't know whether there is a way to completely "hide" the field so I don't have to display it but still use it in jQuery process.

Here is how I am displaying the field as "readonly" in my screen.

> ```
>    ***'<td><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="1" value="' || sys.HTF.escape_sc(c2.codigo_articulo)  || '" readonly></td>'*** ||
> ```

```
   '</tr>');
```

Thanks in advance.

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is what [hidden fields](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#hidden-control) are for. Simply use `type="hidden"` instead of `type="text"` (and omit the `size` and `readonly` attributes):

```
<input type="hidden" name="f_prod_id"
value="' || sys.HTF.escape_sc(c2.codigo_articulo)  || '">
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="1" style="display:none">
```

if you don't want to show or even in future than

```
<input type="hidden" name="f_prod_id" size="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

use `style="display:none;"` so that you can access it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the element still appears in the code and can be referenced via a selector then you're fine.  You can also use .data() depending on the situation.